# Как прочитать строку с русским алфавитом?

Tags: c, строки, ввод

Задача такова: дана строка длиной не более 100 символов, если есть повторяющиеся ПОДРЯД, нужно сделать так, чтобы таковых не было, т.е. оставить только один символ из ряда повторяющихся. Код работает при условии, что человек вводил латиницу и цифры, а если вводил русские буквы, ничего не работает. Что делать?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h> 

int main()
{
    char stroka[100];
    scanf("%100[^\n]", stroka);
    int n = 0;
    int dlina = 0;
    dlina = strlen(stroka);
    while (n<dlina) {
        if (stroka[n]==stroka[n+1]) {
            stroka[n] = '~';
            
        }
        
        n++;
    }
    dlina = strlen(stroka);
    for (int i=0; i<dlina; i++) {
        if (stroka[i]!='~'){
            printf("%c", stroka[i]);
        }
       
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то зависит от используемой кодировки (так что важна ОС и т.п.). У меня на VC++, например, работает. Только вот повторяющиеся — это у вас идущие подряд, это так и надо?

Comment: да, это так и надо, не верно написала условие( а может вы знаете как поменять кодировку?

Comment: А в задаче точно нет условия что будут только латинские буквы/цифры? Потому что разбираться с проблемами с кодировкой это на порядок более сложное занятие чем само задание.

Comment: в задании ничего не сказано об этом, к сожалению. проблема в том, что программа проходит 25/32 тестов, и наша группа решила, что проблема именно в этом, возможно, мы не правы.

Comment: Вообще-то ваш код не работает если в тексте изначально есть символ `~`.

Comment: да, я знаю об этом

Comment: И почему вы тогда грешите на русские буквы, а не на тильду?

Comment: И вообще, не лучше ли спросить у преподавателя какие граничные условия и какая кодировка?

Comment: Неработоспособность проявится при многобайтной кодировке, типа utf-8. Кстати, при вашем решении заполняйте лучше нулями, их-то в строке быть не должно :), только вот длину при выводе не пересчитывайте, а берите прежнюю.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем! Проблема с была не с русским алфавитом) Оставлю здесь свой код, может кому-то пригодится :) Еще раз задание:  В стандартный поток ввода подается строка, состоящая из символов, длиной не более 100 символов. Далее входной поток заканчивается. Необходимо вывести в стандартный поток вывода строку, в которой отсутствуют одинаковые подряд идущие символы: если таковые есть, то заменить всю группу идующих подряд одинаковых на один символ: 'sss' -> 's'.
код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h> 

int main()
{
    char stroka[100];
    scanf("%100[^\n]", stroka);
    
    int i = 0;
    int dlina = strlen(stroka);
     
    int p = 0;
    
    while (i<dlina) {         
        
        if (stroka[i]!=stroka[i+1]) {
            printf("%c", stroka[i]);
            
        } 
        
        else {
            printf("%c", stroka[i]); 
            p = i;
            int n = 0;
            
            while ((stroka[p] == stroka[p+1]) && (p<100)) {
                n++; 
                p++; 
            }
            i += n;
            
        }
        i++;
       
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```